# Rspec: Intercept some data from a controller action and send to/read it within a spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a custom Logger in the middle of my controller method which writes some data to a logfile (`logger.info 'some log data...'`).

Is there any way I can intercept this data or possibly store a copy of this data within something like a string buffer and read it within my spec for processing after it is generated(possibly without stubbing)?

Comment: Store it in a variable? e.g. `@log`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using expectations for the Logger class. Although it's a bit strange to use Rspecs to find items you are logging; if the information is that important maybe store it in a variable? Anywho; the code would be something like:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Logger).to receive(:foo)
```

You can check out more at the docs here: [rspec expect a message on any instance of a class](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class!)